Cómo hago para ubicar un valor en la penúltima fila
Estaba intentando hacer un ejercicio y tengo el dataframe de la imagen:

Entonces lo que busco es que cuando en la columna i/u halla un valor 'r' y si también en la columna BUS los valores pertenecen al mismo grupo como es el caso del 2. Y sí en la columna Tt_tex encuentra un valor que sea diferente de '00:00:00', me lo ubique en esa misma columna Tt_tex pero en la penúltima fila del grupo.
Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:
df_fusionado = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['i/u', 'Terminal'], right_on=['i/u', 'RUTA'], how='left')
df_fusionado['HORA_INI'] = df_fusionado.groupby('BUS')['HORA_INI'].transform(lambda x: [x.iloc[-1]] + ['00:00:00']*(len(x)-1))

df_fusionado['Tt_tex'] = df_fusionado.groupby('BUS')['Tt_tex'].transform(lambda x: ['00:00:00']*(len(x)-1) + [x.iloc[-1]])

df_fusionado.head(20)

Con eso logro que lo ubique en la última fila del grupo pero cuando le pongo el -2
df_fusionado['Tt_tex'] = df_fusionado.groupby('BUS')['Tt_tex'].transform(lambda x: ['00:00:00']*(len(x)-1) + [x.iloc[-2]])

Me sale este error ---> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
Entonces me gustaría saber cómo hago para acceder a la penúltima fila. Gracias de antemano.

Ten en cuenta que puedes tener grupos con un solo registro (fila) y para esos grupos el indice -2 no existe, por eso el error. En tu ejemplo los grupos "BUS 1" y "BUS 6" y "BUS 7" solo tiene una fila. -1 va a funcionar siempre, igual que 0, porque cada grupo va a tener siempre al menos una fila, o no habría grupo....

Bueno en realidad ese es en un dataframe de ejemplo porque el dataframe final no va a tener ningún grupo de un registro. Sólo estaba usando ese como prueba de lo que quiero hacer.
